# axios post method 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a JSON file, editing it and trying send it back to server. But when I use post method it throws an error 400 bad request.In  response shows "no template_id or no template_json presented".  What could be the problem?

```
saveData() {
    const { data } = this.state
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    axios
      .post(
        "http://dev.candidates.hrmessenger.com/stage/set-template",
        data,

        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        },
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says *"no template_id or no template_json presented"* — So provide one of those. (If you think you are already, then we can't tell why: Your question lacks a [mcve])

Comment: presumably you didn't include some data with those field names, or not in the place in the JSON where the server was expecting to see them. Since we a) have no idea what format the server expects you to send data, or what is expects you to include, and b) have only an incomplete sample of the data you sent, it's a little difficult to give specific advice. If you'd like more help, please provide more relevant information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

> data.template_id = 1;

```
saveData() {
    const { data } = this.state
    data.template_id = 1;
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    axios
      .post(
        "http://dev.candidates.hrmessenger.com/stage/set-template",
        data,

        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        },
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

You missed the parameter template_id, or you need to ask from your API developer to send the documentations of the POST Method API.