# Error 400 (Bad Request) when calling server using POST method in MERN

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, mern

I created a delete user account button in my reactjs application. When this button is clicked, a form is displayed where the user must enter the password of the current account and then click *Delete* in order to delete the account. However, when I test this functionality, when I click on the *Delete* button, this does not delete the user account and in the command line I get the error:

**POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/delete_profile 400 (Bad Request)**

Here is my file `DeleteAccount.js`:

```
<form onSubmit={handleDeleteUser}>
            ...
              <TextField
                error={error && error.password ? true : false}
                helperText={error && error.password ? error.password : null}
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                 ...
              />
             ...
          </form>
```

my `useDeleteProfile.js` file:

```
try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`${url}/api/auth/delete_profile`,initialState)
              ...
        history.push('/')
}
```

my `Auth.js` file:

```
const DeleteAccount = require("../controllers/Auth/DeleteProfile")
  ...
router.post('/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

my `DeleteProfile.js` file :

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const { password } = req.body
  let error = {}

  if (!password || password.trim().length === 0) {
    error.password = 'password must be required'
  }

  
  if (Object.keys(error).length) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error })
  }

  try {

    const verifyPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!verifyPassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'password is incorrect' })
    } else {

    await User.deleteMany({ user: req.userId })
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User Deleted Successfully' })

    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json({error:"Something went wrong"})
  }

}
```

To resolve this error, I replaced the `POST` method with the `DELETE` method since it was a delete operation. Like this in my  `useDeleteProfile.js` file:

```
 const { data } = await axios.delete(`${url}/api/auth/delete_profile`,initialState)
```

And like this in my `Auth.js` file :

```
router.delete('/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

now, I obtain the following error:

**DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/auth/delete_profile 400 (Bad Request)**

. So I modified my `useDeleteProfile.js` file like this, but nothing:

```
const { data } = await axios.delete(`${url}/api/auth/delete_profile`,
       initialState,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      },
    )
```

I also modified my Auth.js file like this :

```
router.delete('/api/auth/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

but now, I obtain the following error:

**DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/auth/delete_profile 404 (Not Found)**

I also looked on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354046/axios-post-method-400-bad-request) but without success. Someone can help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are using an incorrect routing path.

Below is the correct way

For **POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/delete_profile** use

```
router.post('/api/auth/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

For **DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/auth/delete_profile** use

```
router.delete('/api/auth/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

Comment: I tested your solution but it didn't resolve my problem and I get errors. See on the question for more details

Comment: For incorrect route path it will show 404 error not 400 error.

Comment: This error may be arise due to incorrect password or  can you check the password key that you are sending to server in initialState axios request

Answer (score 0):

Why you have added /api/auth/  prefix only put your relative path

```
router.delete('/api/auth/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

replace to

```
router.delete('/delete_profile',authRequired, DeleteAccount)
```

Comment: I was testing the solution offered by the second answer you can see.

Comment: can you show me github repo so that i can test it

Comment: Here is the  [frontend repository](https://github.com/gouneken/frontend); DeleteAccount.js file is located in SecurityAndLogin folder location. Here is the  [backend repository](https://github.com/gouneken/backend) , the Auth.js file has been modified and from this file you can find the location of the created file. Thanks again for the help Harsh Mangalam.